# Manually setting values in 2Darrays C++

Tags: c++, arrays, variables

Simply put an array can be defined with

```
int arrayValues = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

How do you define in a similar manor with a double array to avoid writing this out...

```
int magicArray[rowSize][colSize];

magicArray[0][0] = 4;
magicArray[0][1] = 3;
magicArray[0][2] = 8;

magicArray[1][0] = 9;
magicArray[1][1] = 5;
magicArray[1][2] = 1;

magicArray[2][0] = 2;
magicArray[2][1] = 7;
magicArray[2][2] = 6;
```

Is it possible to write something like...

```
int magicArray[rowSize][colSize] = { {x,y,value}, {0,0,1}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A two dimensional array is the same as a one dimensional array in memory. They are both just pointers. Create your array as one-dimensional, initialize it, then create your two dimensional array and point it to the same pointer.

I do not have a testing environment handy and have not worked with C++ in a while so use this with caution and just as a starting point:

```
int tempArray[rowSize*colSize]={4,3,8,9,5,1,2...};
int magicArray[rowSize][colSize];
magicArray=tempArray;
```

Comment: Would you mind writing an example? I don't quite follow

Comment: I edited my post but be aware that it may not be valid C++ and in need of tweaking.

Comment: Ahhh awesome okay I get it. Thanks so much!